# Dynamic height of UITableViewCell with storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have read alot about dynamic height for `UITableViewCell` and for the life of me I cannot get it working.

I have a uilabel with dynamic content within a dynamic cell.

I am using the storyboard and have the constraints as so :

[image]

I am populating the table using

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"labelCell";

    detailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[detailTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.dynamicLabel.text = sectionString;

    return cell;
}
```

I do not know why everything I have tried has failed. I am thinking it may be the connections on the uiLabel?

Comment: I believe you still need to calculate the height individually for each cell at `heightforrowatindexpath`.

Comment: Try `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method of `UITableView`. And if you need to change the height of `UILabel` according to cellHeight, add `Bottom space` of `UILabel` to `container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it , Right :

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSString *text = myText;// [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        CGSize size;
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
            // code here for iOS 5.0,6.0 and so on
            CGSize fontSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];
            size = fontSize;
        }
        else {
            // code here for iOS 7.0
            NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:19], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                  nil];
            CGRect fontSizeFor7 = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(571, 500)
                                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                  attributes:attributesDictionary
                                                     context:nil];
            size = fontSizeFor7.size;

        }
        NSLog(@"indexPAth %ld %f",(long)indexPath.section, size.height);

        return size.height +30 ;

    }
```

Finally, at the delegate of cellForRowAtIndexPath: don't forget to make the UILabel flexible for text :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ........
    cell.dynamicLabel.text = sectionString;
     cell.dynamicLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: hi @kumar KL . This approach works howwver seems to have a max size. Can I confirm a few things? Why is +30 added to the height at the end? And is the boudingRectWithSize limiting it to a max height?

Comment: +30 is just for spacing between text and Cell, you can change it to your need . And boudingRectWithSize - its not a constant value, change according to your label